# How to configure i18n pt-BR on ruby on rails App, getting an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to configure pt-BR on ruby on rails using i18n.

I have added on the file `config/application.rb`

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :pt-BR
```

And on the controller `controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :set_locale

    def set_locale
        I18n.locale = params[:lang] || I18n.default_locale
    end
end
```

When i run `rails s` i get the error:

```
: uninitialized constant MyApp::Application::BR (NameError)
```

If i change the `:pt-BR` to `:pt`, for example, it works fine, but not working with `pt-BR`

Any suggestions to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use quotes around `:"pt-BR"`, instead of only `:pt-BR`.

try that:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :"pt-BR"
```

source:
https://guiarails.com.br/i18n.html